# I cannot stop playing a wav file while it is playing in playsync mode in C#

Tags: c#

I want to play two wav file and they are playing file with this code:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked = true)
{
string[] arr = new string[3];

            arr[0] = "E:\\data\\E\\55765.wav";
            arr[1] = "E:\\data\\E\\ablate.wav";
            arr[2] = "E:\\data\\E\\pf1.wav";


            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {

                player.SoundLocation = arr[i];
                player.Load();
                player.PlaySync();

            }
```

But once the play is started I am assigning a button to stop the player by this code

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.stop();

        }
```

But this is not working. But if I use player.Play() only the last wav file is playing. Please help...

Comment: You need to put the code in a different thread. Or  do an async operation. For more information on async operations, read C# in depth by Jon Skeet.

Comment: How to get this property in C# MediaPlayer.IsBuffering Property